# Render to different view Cakephp 3

Tags: view, controller, render, cakephp-3.0, var

I'm beginning to work on CakePHP and I'm stucked on a problem.

I have an Articles controller inside a blog project and I want to display the X last articles on my home page which is the home.ctp in the Pages template.

Here is my Articles function in Articles controller :

```
  public function recentArticles(){
     $recentArticles = $this->Articles->find('all', [
      'limit' => 5,
      'order' => 'Articles.created DESC'
     ]);
     $this->set('recentArticles', $recentArticles);
     $this->render('/Pages/home');
}
```

And here is my section in the template where I try to display the articles :

```
<?php foreach ($recentArticles as $article): ?>
<section class="col-4-ligne">
  <?=$this->Html->image('slide3.jpg', array('alt' => 'nom du slide', 'class' => 'img-responsive'))?>
  <a href="categories/view/1"><section class="btn btn-lg btn-danger principale"><?= $article->title ?></section></a>
</section>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I tried to use $this->render in the controller, I also tried to put my function into the Pages controller like this :

```
  public function recentArticles(){
     $this->loadModel('Articles');
     $recentArticles = $this->Articles->find('all', [
      'limit' => 5,
      'order' => 'Articles.created DESC'
     ]);
     $this->set('recentArticles', $recentArticles);
     $this->render('/Pages/home');
}
```

But in each case I get the same error in my template which is "Undefined variable: recentArticles".

Any idea ?

EDIT : Ok so I didn't success to call the recentArticles function so I put the code into the default function display like this and it works. 
I don't know if it's good way to do it.

```
    public function display()
{
    $path = func_get_args();

    $count = count($path);
    if (!$count) {
        return $this->redirect('/');
    }
    $page = $subpage = null;

    if (!empty($path[0])) {
        $page = $path[0];
    }
    if (!empty($path[1])) {
        $subpage = $path[1];
    }
    $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage'));

    //Latest articles
    $this->loadModel('Articles');
    $recentArticles = $this->Articles->find('all', [
     'limit' => 5,
     'order' => 'Articles.created DESC'
    ]);
    $this->set('recentArticles', $recentArticles);

    try {
        $this->render(implode('/', $path));
    } catch (MissingTemplateException $e) {
        if (Configure::read('debug')) {
            throw $e;
        }
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Comment: i test your code, and its work for me, no error. please check for misstyped or misspelled

Comment: I have checked and all the variables have the same name everywhere, no error.

Comment: then check your articles routes in routes.php